# Javascript can't replace string

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

`_.replace()` doesn't replacing anything in string. I tried like 5 different ways to do it but still nothing and I guess you are my last hope.

My code:

```js
const http = require("http");
const dateformat = require("dateformat");
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'ewangelia',
    description: "Wyświetla dzisiejszą ewangelię",
    execute(message) {
        const url = 'http://feed.evangelizo.org/v2/reader.php?'; // date=20201203&type=reading&content=GSP&lang=PL
        let formatedURL;
        let now = new Date();
        let today = dateformat(now, 'yyyymmdd');
        let author = '', content = '', temp = [];
        formatedURL = url+'date='+today+'&'+'type=reading&content=GSP&lang=PL'; //ewangelia
        //
        http.request(formatedURL, (response) => {
            var str = '';
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                str += chunk;
              });
              response.on('end', function () {
                content = str;
                let temp = content.split('<br /><br /><br />');
                temp.pop();
                temp[0] = temp[0].replace('<br />', "");
                content = temp[0];
                embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('⛪ Ewangelia na dziś ⛪')
                .addField(' Ewangelia:', content);

                message.channel.send(embed);
              });
        }).end();
    },
};
```

I want to get rid of `<br />`

Output:
[image: output]

Comment: Either use `replaceAll` or replace with regexp... `replace(/<br/?>/, '')`.

Comment: `replace` only replaces the first occurrence: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a regular expression with global flag to replace all occurrence of a pattern.

```js
const str = 'some text <br /> here is another text <br /> some text again';
console.log(str.replace(/<br \/>/g, ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `replaceAll()` instead of `replace()`

Like this:

```js
temp[0] = temp[0].replaceAll('<br />', '');
```

See [replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) for more information

Comment: temp[0].replaceAll is not a function

Comment: is temp[0] a string?

Answer (score 1):

```
.replace(/char you wanna replace/gi,'replacement')
```

the `/g` to check all of the strings containing "char you wanna replace" then replacing it
also you can use `.replaceall()`